# How to restart Tekton PipelineRun, having a pipeline-run.yml defined in git (e.g. using Cloud Native Buildpacks)?

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, buildpack, tekton

We want to use [the official Tekton buildpacks task](https://hub.tekton.dev/tekton/task/buildpacks) from Tekton Hub to run our builds using Cloud Native Buildpacks. The [buildpacks documentation for Tekton](https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/tekton/) tells us to install the `buildpacks` & `git-clone` Task from Tekton Hub, create `Secret`, `ServiceAccount`, `PersistentVolumeClaim` and [a Tekton `Pipeline`](https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/tekton/#43-pipeline).

As the configuration is parameterized, we don't want to start our Tekton pipelines using a huge kubectl command but instead configure the `PipelineRun` using a separate `pipeline-run.yml` YAML file ([as also stated in the docs](https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/tekton/#5-create--apply-pipelinerun)) containing the references to the `ServiceAccount`, workspaces, image name and so on:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  name: buildpacks-test-pipeline-run
spec:
  serviceAccountName: buildpacks-service-account # Only needed if you set up authorization
  pipelineRef:
    name: buildpacks-test-pipeline
  workspaces:
    - name: source-workspace
      subPath: source
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: buildpacks-source-pvc
    - name: cache-workspace
      subPath: cache
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: buildpacks-source-pvc
  params:
    - name: image
      value: <REGISTRY/IMAGE NAME, eg gcr.io/test/image > # This defines the name of output image
```

Now running the Tekton pipeline once is no problem using `kubectl apply -f pipeline-run.yml`. But how can we restart or reuse this YAML-based configuration for all the other pipelines runs?

Answer (score 3):

[tkn cli](https://github.com/tektoncd/cli/) has the switch --use-pipelinerun to the command `tkn pipeline start`, what this command does is to reuse the params/workspaces from that pipelinerun and create a new one, so effectively "restarting" it.

so to 'restart' the pipelinerun pr1 which belong to the pipeline p1 you would do:

`tkn pipeline start p1 --use-pipelinerun pr1`

maybe we should have a easier named command, I kicked the discussion sometime ago feel free to contribute a feedback :

https://github.com/tektoncd/cli/issues/1091

Answer (score 2):

There are some discussions about that topic in the Tekton GitHub project - see [tektoncd/pipeline/issues/664](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/issues/664) and [tektoncd/pipeline/issues/685](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/issues/685). Since Tekton is heavily based on Kubernetes, [all Tekton objects are Kubernetes CRDs - which are in fact immutable](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/issues/897#issuecomment-495090130). **So it is intended to not be able to re-run an already run `PipelineRun`.**

But as also discussed in [tektoncd/pipeline/issues/685](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/issues/685#issuecomment-477121846) we can simply use the `generateName` variable of the `metadata` field like this:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  generateName: buildpacks-test-pipeline-run-
spec:
  serviceAccountName: buildpacks-service-account # Only needed if you set up authorization
  pipelineRef:
    name: buildpacks-test-pipeline
  workspaces:
    - name: source-workspace
      subPath: source
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: buildpacks-source-pvc
    - name: cache-workspace
      subPath: cache
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: buildpacks-source-pvc
  params:
    - name: image
      value: <REGISTRY/IMAGE NAME, eg gcr.io/test/image > # This defines the name of output image
```

Running `kubectl create -f pipeline-run.yml` will now work multiple times and kind of "restart" our Pipeline, while creating a new `PipelineRun` object like `buildpacks-test-pipeline-run-dxcq6` everytime the command is issued.

Keep in mind to delete old `PipelineRun` objects once in a while though.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restart a `pipelinerun`.
Since in tekton, a `pipelinerun` is one time execution for a `pipeline`(treat as template), so it should not able to be restart, another `kubectl apply` for `pipelinerun` is another execution...